# Is there a way to put a shadow behind white symbols (legend/layout/QGIS)?

Tags: qgis, line, legend

I'm used to use white lines to outline municipalities along with the satellite image, and to outline colored polygons with white line to make them stand out. However, when I represent them in the layout, what I have left is to use a polygon with a black outline. Is there a better solution, besides using a raster?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you mean in the layers panel? You can change the theme/style in Settings - Options - Application to for example Grey.

Comment: she_weeds answered exactly what I wanted to know. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about depicting an all-white symbol in the print layout legend, where the background is also white, you could use a **custom symbol** with a subtle drop shadow/outline that applies only to the legend and won't change your actual layer symbology.

Select the legend item in your layout, double click the legend item with the white symbol, and enable Custom Symbol and edit the symbol as below.

[image]

When defining the custom symbol, you can choose to make your symbol more visible by adding another element(s) to the symbol (use the plus or duplicate buttons as below). For example, you might create another outline element, place it below the original white element (using the arrow buttons), make it a darker colour and 0.3mm thicker than the white outline.

You could also choose to use Draw Effects on the original white outline (scroll down to the bottom and click on the star as below) and add a drop shadow.

[image: click to enlarge]

Result with drop shadow -

[image]

---

Alternatively you could use a different colour for your print layout legend background to make the white stand out; select the legend item and in Item Properties scroll all the way down to Background.